# Gauge invariance of the quadratic graviton Lagrangian

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, gauge-invariance, diffeomorphism-invariance

I've been reading up on how the linearised Einstein field equations can be derived from a field theoretic perspective, by constructing the most general Lagrangian for a massless spin-2 field, $h_{\mu\nu}$, compatible with locality and Lorentz invariance. This is given by $$\mathcal{L}=a\partial_{\lambda}h^{\mu\nu}\partial^{\lambda}h_{\mu\nu}+b \partial_{\mu}h^{\mu\lambda}\partial^{\nu}h_{\lambda\nu}+c\partial_{\mu}h\partial_{\nu}h^{\mu\nu}+d\partial_{\mu}h\partial^{\mu}h$$ Now, the requirement of Lorentz invariance requires that $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under the transformation $$h_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow h_{\mu\nu}+2\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}$$ where $\xi^{\mu}$ is a generic 4-vector. This transformation corresponds exactly to a gauge transformation of the spin-2 field.

In principle, one should be able to determine the forms of the coefficients $a$, $b$ $c$ and $d$. However, it seems impossible to do so without relaxing the condition of strict Lorentz invariance of $\mathcal{L}$ to requiring that it is invariant up to a boundary term. What does this mean for the gauge invariance of the theory? If it is to correspond to GR then the theory should be invariant under these linearised diffeomorphisms, right?

What am I missing? If someone could enlighten me on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: "...the requirement of Lorentz invariance requires..." no, that transformation corresponds to diffeomorphism invariance. Your Lagrangian is Lorentz invariant regardless of this latter invariance.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  If one studies how the spin-2 field transforms under Lorentz transformations though, one finds that $U(\Lambda)h^{\mu\nu}U^{-1}(\Lambda)=(\Lambda^{-1})^{\mu}_{\;\;\sigma}(\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}_{\;\;\rho}h^{\sigma\rho} +2\partial^{(\mu}\xi_{_{\Lambda}}^{\nu)}$, so isn't such a transformation needed to negate the non-covariant part of the transformation?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. You are going Weinberg style, aren't you? E.g., $h^{0\mu}=\partial_i h^{i\mu}=0$, etc.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  I've actually been following these notes: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://phys.columbia.edu/~nicolis/GR_from_LI.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiLn76k-arXAhVEvBoKHdiHAmsQFggmMAA&usg=AOvVaw0prV9uVs0OP9tHmFusi-dW but this may be equivalent to Weinberg. I didn't intend to gauge fix $h_{\mu\nu}$. Does the spin-2 field only transform like this under Lorentz transformations if it is gauge fixed?

Comment: Yep, that document has "Weinberg" written all over it. See e.g. the references.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Ah apologies, I somehow managed to gloss over that bit. So how does a spin 2 field transform under Lorentz transformations when it's not gauge fixed? Do you know of any notes that go into detail on this subject?

Comment: Unfortunately, that question is kind of meaningless. In the approach of your notes, there is no gauge-fixing. The object $h$ is constructed from first principles, and is shown to satisfy the Coulomb condition a posteriori. Such a condition is not imposed, but it appears naturally from the properties of the little group of massless particles. On the other hand, in covariant approaches one introduces a *different* field $h'$, which is postulated to transform as a true rank-2 tensor. Only if the theory is gauge invariant do both approaches agree. But in principle they are different.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform So in the covariant approach does one simply require that the action is gauge invariant such that the Lagrangian is invariant up to boundary terms?

Comment: Yes. (Well, there are some exceptions, such as topological field theories...)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Do you know of any good notes that go into detail on the spin-2 derivation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as soon as one neglects curvature by resorting to a linear perturbation around the Minkowski metric, one is then forced to use the tenets of classical field theory. One of these is that the fields (in this case the 10 independent $h$ functions) are Schwartz test functions, i.e functions whose modulus and spacetime differentials of all orders go fast to 0, as the „radius of Minkowski spacetime" is pushed to $+\infty$. In this simple perspective, there is no discussion of "Lorentz invariance of the Lagrangian (density)". The true invariance is imposed upon the Lagrangian action, i.e. to the **integral** on the flat spacetime continuum **of the Lagrangian density**. So there's no "relaxing" needed, it is all there in the standard assumptions of classical field theory.

Feynman in his GR lectures explains how one derives the a,b,c,d factors. That is an elegant method reminding me of the Pauli and Fierz one. On the other hand, one can linearize by brute force the Hilbert-Einstein action and get the 4 coefficients. This works, too.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to the spin-1 case of electromgnetism in which the Lagrangian density is already gauge invariant before considering the action.

Comment: In classical field theory functions are **not** in general of the Schwartz type. Or rather, there is no need to assume them to be. For our purposes, it suffices to take $h\in C^2_c(\mathbb R^4)$.

Comment: Note also that OP is taking $h$ to be the gauge-fixed field (Coulomb? DeDonder?), where $h^{0\mu}=\partial_i h^{i\mu}=h^\mu{}_\mu=0$ , so the field has only two independent components.

Comment: Well, this is a too stringent assumption. Spacetime is in principle infinite, so there is a reason to expect that fields "stretch" to infinity.